# Can't install GCC6 using conda

Tags: gcc, anaconda

I find that conda can install gcc-6 : https://anaconda.org/salford_systems/gcc-6

But I met a error:

> [user@login2 bin]$ conda install -c salford_systems gcc-6=6.2.0
>   Fetching package metadata ........... Solving package specifications:
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '

Also, I tried install gcc5 and get the same error.

I use redhat. Does anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can [search anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=gcc-6) for `gcc-6` and install it using e.g.:

`conda install -c omgarcia gcc-6`